# How do I add HTML to my posts using the editor?

Tags: support, status-norepro, markdown

Umm, I feel dumb for asking this, but how to I add HTML into my questions and answers with this editor? Sometimes [it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324764/accessing-a-frame-within-a-frame) for me and sometimes it doesn't...

I know about the faq, that the site uses markdown and there are allowed tags as well.

---

#### Related:

> - [How Does Stackoverflow Work? (The Official FAQ)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq)
> - [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed)

Comment: OK, to clarify, since I can't even edit my post above... I added some HTML to this post.. it didn't show up, but I've noticed that if I go back and edit the post and add HTML tags, it works. Is this a bug or intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean.

Do you mean show html code snippets?  If so, indent your code four spaces or select and use the "code" button on the toolbar (Ctrl-K as a keyboard shortcut).  `<pre>` and `<code>` tags also work, and you can use backticks (`) for inline snippets.

Do you mean add formatting to your question using html? If so, common html tags should work as expected.  However, the input box was really designed for [markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and so it will also apply markdown rules anywhere they fit.

Comment: Today when I tried to add an <html> tag to my answer or even <body> it didn't work, but if you look at the link I have in the top post... it's worked before.

Comment: Oh well, I'll just re-edit my posts when I have to or keep using the backticks, that seems to work better

Answer (score 0):

(Re: It works) That's just embedding code. You put all of this in a <pre><code>block and escape the '<' with &lt; However the easiest way is to paste it in, select it, and press <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> or click on the 101/010 icon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I've noticed a couple of time that using the backtick rather than four leading spaces works better for some HTML.